# Does chess improve our intelligence?

Tags: beginner, iq

This is my first question in Chess, so I hope my question is simple.

I know about chess but I am not a regular player. But my friend told me that everyday play chess is good for your mind and also for improving memory power. Is this correct?

And also I don't know some of the move rules. So, please give me some suggestion to improve my chess knowledge.

Comment: Start from these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_as_mental_training and https://www.quora.com/Does-chess-skill-correlate-with-intelligence and links therein.

Comment: A new analysis rebuts the claim that there is no link between general intelligence and expertise in a specific arena such as chess.

Comment: @mujaffars link?

Comment: http://www.psmag.com/books-and-culture/champion-chess-players-smart-yes-question-65735

TOM JACOBS  SEP 5, 2013

http://www.psmag.com/author/tomjacobs

Comment: I found that in a day that I think hard I play better quality chess, on the other hand in the day that I play chess I have no improvement in quality of my thinking.

Answer (score 4):

So far, studies I‘ve seen mentioned in newspapers making a claim either for or against a correlation between chess and intelligence strike me as highly dubious in their methodology. That‘s not surprising, since the concept of a “general intelligence” is itself dubious. (And it’s not even entirely clear in every context what “intelligence” actually means.)

Chess is basically a duel that two people fight with their minds. One would expect that as a pastime it’s more attractive to people who enjoy exercising their minds in various areas in general. Therefore, it wouldn’t be surprising to find that among good chess players there would also be more people than average that are good at mathematics, spatial visualisation, music and arts, programming etc.

(Speaking metaphorically: A rooster makes cock-a-doodle-doo, because the sun goes up. It's not the other way around: The sun doesn't rise because of the rooster.)

Developing, for instance, a good memory for chess games and long variations doesn’t automatically grant a good memory for reciting poetry or repeating the dance steps in a choreography or the memory necessary to keep one’s focus through deciphering a particularly difficult classical Greek text. Nor does it make you good at drawing portraits (which is for a very substantial part about having a good short term visual memory).

There *might* be some soft form of synenergy in that playing chess increases brain activity, brain metabolism etc. which conceivably *might* have a positive effect on other mental activities. That, though, would also go the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

The folks at Lumosity.com got into trouble by claiming that expertise in their brain games would translate to expertise in other related brain experiences. That said, I feel that my experience with chess has helped me understand some core life principles that may or may not be related to general intelligence.

```
Life lesson 1: arrogance gives birth to mistakes
Life lesson 2: impulsiveness is your enemy
Life lesson 3: the more you work at chess (or anything) the better you'll become at that same thing
Life lesson 4: chess can help with your relationship with your son or daughter
Life lesson 5: streaks of success and failure are certain and often turn without warning
Life lesson 6: sleep is directly related to intellectual performance (chess or otherwise)
Life lesson 7: mood, distractions, and overall health are factors to be considered
Life lesson 8: you must take risks in order to make significant gains
Life lesson 9: good sportsmanship is more important than victory
Life lesson 10: nearly everyone is beatable and nearly everyone could beat you on a given day
```

So, again, I am not sure that chess intelligence translates to overall intelligence, but some intelligent lessons can be gained from the pursuit of getting better at chess. Try [chess.com](http://chess.com), [chessgames.com](http://chessgames.com) and [chessclub.com](http://chessclub.com) to learn these life lessons and more all the while improving your game.

Comment: Lesson for myself: Try to distinguish perceived risk and true risk. If you spend time reacting to false perceived risk, you will fail to the true risk

Comment: @jf328 Very good point. All too often I fail to assess the danger of a given situation.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Chess promotes several skills in you:

1. Memory, and especially photographical memory. Getting used to calculate and move the pieces several moves ahead can really give your head a boost!
2. Creativity, yes the Tactical thinking in chess, finding combinations and showing your art on the board will make you more creative.
3. Strategical thinking, Chess is a lot relying on strategy and this one helps you to take decisions accurately in your life and organize your daily tasks, and eventually being a really successful person.

And let's not forget that being good at chess will give a quiet great impression to people towards you, you will be that intelligent logical great minded person in their eyes ;)

Comment: Is there any scientific data that can back this up?

Comment: I think this answer needs to be improved by adding some supporting evidence. As it is, I have no way of knowing whether or not anything in this answer is true.

Answer (score 1):

Chess is game between two Intellectuals, two Wills & two Egos. ~~ Garry Kasparov.

Now when you ask that Chess improves your intelligence ??

This answers is just the two sides of the Coin.

A direct answer is Chess does not increase your IQ . If you are hoping that Chess would increase your Intelligence Quotient then please note that there is no such Theory or evidence.

but

Chess helps you to think objectively , make quick decisions and helps you in strategic thinking . As Chess is Gymnasium of the mind it constantly allows the exercise of your Brain Cells and does not make your Brain grow old with time . As Intelligence is not directly proportional to just the IQ level but with other factors associated with it like knowledge, awareness , experience so with that said Chess improves your intelligence .

Answer (score 0):

I doubt chess is better for your brain than other intellectual exercises. The brain is like a muscle, the more exercise it gets, the stronger it gets.

So if the comparison is between chess and watching TV, yes, chess is better for your brain. But if the comparison is between chess and solving crosswords or logic puzzles, I think you're doing well, either way.

Answer (score -2):

Chess does not have that much of a direct correlation to IQ.  There should be no formula.

[Expert Chess Players Are Smart?](http://www.psmag.com/books-and-culture/champion-chess-players-smart-yes-question-65735)

Comment: Ya I know but she told me that it improves your creativity and also your memory and the main is **problem solving skills**.

Comment: I don't thimk so. Better way play the Logical android games like `cut the rope`,`pudding monsters`, `clash of clans`, `roll the ball` etc. By the way who is she?

Comment: I don't think so. Kasparov has a book on how chess can influence one's life.

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: @Glorfindel http://www.psmag.com/books-and-culture/champion-chess-players-smart-yes-question-65735

Comment: @mujaffars I am not agree with you. Just check with Chess advantages in Google.

Answer (score -2):

There has been some research.  However, the quality of that research is considered exploratory and descriptive so no firm conclusions can be made.  It does seem to help with [academic achievement](http://education.jhu.edu/PD/newhorizons/strategies/topics/thinking-skills/chess/)